# When to use "bum someone out"

Tags: phrase-usage

When to use "bum someone out"
And when to use "annoy someone"

I have searched the meaning of both the phrase on the internet but I am little confused when to use "bum someone out" . I know a little about the usage of "annoy someone" but I am confused when to use "bum someone out" instead of "annoy someone"

I think "to annoy someone" means to irritate someone and "bum someone out" means to irritate someone, bore someone and a kind of ruin someone's fun (means rain on someones parade).

And I also feel that "bum someone out" is of higher degree and quite more effective or kind of more offensive.

Comment: See [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/burn-out). Also see the meaning of the noun “[burnout](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/burnout)”.

Comment: @user2684291 I made the same mistake at first. This font kind of makes "bum" look like "burn". But he's asking about BUM someone out, not BURN.

Comment: @JamieB Oh, right, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that to *annoy* means to **irritate**, but to *bum someone out* means to make them **sad or depressed**.

For example, let's say you and I are going on a trip somewhere. I plug my .mp3 player into your car's stereo, and the first song to start playing is *YMCA* by the Village People.

You say, "Ugh! Shut that off or change the song! I don't like disco music, and I can't stand the Village People."

I might say:

> Sorry, I didn't mean to **annoy** you.

The next song that comes up is *Cryin'* by Aerosmith. You used to enjoy dancing to this song with your ex-girlfriend, but the two of you just broke up three weeks ago. You tell me, "That's better – I generally like Aerosmith. But Tara and I used to dance to that song a lot, and I don't think I'm ready to listen to this right now."

I answer:

> Sorry, I didn't mean to **bum you out**.

---

**Epilogue**: the next 12 songs that come up on my .mp3 player are all happy and upbeat; they turn out to be excellent driving music. They don't annoy you, and they don't bum you out. It turns out to be a good road trip after all.